# Proper use of Checkboxes in C# WebApp View

Tags: c#, razor, checkbox, view

I have a Checkbox in my View right now that looks like this:

```
@Html.CheckBox("check", true)
```

How can I give it value, name and id manually?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the CheckBox property like this

```
@Html.CheckBox("check", true, new {id = "Your Id"})
```

To understand more about this properties please refer to below MSDN link.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.checkbox(v=vs.118).aspx